# Vectors for Game Programming

Tags: actionscript-3

Im not sure how to use vectors correctly in game programming. I have been reading advanced game design with flash which shows you how to create a vector with a start point and endpoint and how to use that for games, for example the start point would be used for a characters position in a game and the x and y length would be used for velocity. But since I have started looking online  I have found that vectors are usually just x and y with no start point or end point and a character would be moved by having a position vector and a velocity vector and acceleration vector. I have started creating my own vector class. And wondered what the reasons for and against each method are. Or is it completely not important?

Comment: I don't know game development in flash. But with DirectX it's just like you said: a vector for position, one for velocity, one for orientation.

Comment: You might also take a look into the [game development stack exchange site](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/). They will often be better for answering questions like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially a vector means direction. Classical vector is used in physics to present a velocity so that the vector direction stands for the heading and the vector length is a speed.But in graphics  vectors are used also to present position. So if you have some point, let's say, in 2d space  noted by x ,y it remains point if you don't want to know in what  direction it set relating to the origin which is usually a center of the coordinate system. In 2d graphics  we deal with Cartesian coordinate system which has an origin in top left corner of the screen. But you can also have a direction of some vector relative to any other point in the space.That is why you have also vector operations like addition, subtracting ,dot product, cross product. All those help you to measure distances and angles between vectors. I would suggest you to buy a book on graphics programming. Most of them introduce an easy to grasp primer to vector math.And you don't need to write a vector class in AS 3.0 You have a generic one - Vector3d

Comment: yeah i was just writing a class to try and get a better understanding of how it works. thanks for the advice. Are there any books on graphics programming you could recommend?

Comment: Yeah, for the beginners I would suggest  "3d math primer for graphics and game development " by Dunn & Parberry. You can mark my answer btw, if you think it helps; )